# Need to access text of record in dropdown index

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to build some handling for OnRowUpdating in my GridView gvTaskDashboard. I am wanting to check that if a Status dropdown list has Complete selected, that a date has been entered into the Complete Date textbox. I'm sure the problem is in my if statement trying to test for Complete, but because the dropdown is bound to the index of a sql table, I'm not sure how to check for the text value of the selected index. I'm sure I could get by with using `if (ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "5")` for example, but as a coder, I would think checking for "Complete" makes more sense from a maintenance standpoint.

Markup for DDL

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ddlStatusSQL" 
DataTextField="TaskStatusName" DataValueField="TaskStatusID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TaskStatusID") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

SQL DataSource for DDL

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ddlStatusSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProWorxConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [TaskStatusID], [TaskStatusName] FROM [tblTaskStatus] 
ORDER BY [TaskStatusType], [TaskStatusName]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

CodeBehind

```
protected void gvTask_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = gvTaskDashboard.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    // Get Controls
    DropDownList ddlStatus = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ddlStatus");
    TextBox txtCompDate = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtCompDate");

    // Test for Complete Date if Complete status selected
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCompDate.Text) && ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "Complete")
    {
        // Throw Error
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "error", "alert('Enter Complete Date if Status is Complete.');", true);
    }
    else { TaskDashboardSQL.Update(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi give this a whirl:

```
ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text == "Complete"
```